# Future Method: Too many SOQL: 201

Tags: apex

I am getting this error in my code randomly, when I really never have before. The code is live in Prod so I am eager to fix it ASAP.. Can somoeone assist me in figuring out why I am getting this Error for line 91?

Error - "Too many SOQL queries: 201"

Here is the class.

```
public class Zenefits_Time_Off implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts {


public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    Zenefits_Time_Off.makeCallout();
}


@future(callout = true)
public static void makeCallout() {

    List<Time_Off_Request__c> torToUpdate = new List<Time_Off_Request__c> ();
    string url = ''; 
    system.debug('before while');
    while (url != null) {
        url = makeHttpCall(url, torToUpdate);
        system.debug('after while');
    }
    database.insert (torToUpdate);
    system.debug('SECONDTOR ' + torToUpdate); 
}

public static String makeHttpCall(String url, List<Time_Off_Request__c> torToUpdate) {
    map<String,Id> ProjectList = new Map<string,Id>();
                    List<pse__Proj__c> tempProjectList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM pse__Proj__c WHERE Name Like 'PTO%'LIMIT 1];
                        for (pse__Proj__c proj : tempProjectList) {
                        ProjectList.put('pto',proj.Id);
                        }
    string nextUrl = '';
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setHeader();
    request.setEndpoint(url);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) { 
        // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of posts.
        Map<String, Object> wrapper = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        if (wrapper.containsKey('data')) {
            Map<String, Object> wrapper2 = (Map<String, Object>) wrapper.get('data');
            if (wrapper2.containsKey('data')) {
                nextUrl = (String) wrapper2.get('next_url');
                system.debug('next URL' + nextUrl);
                List<Object> vacationRequests = (List<Object>) wrapper2.get('data');
                System.debug('Received the following vacation requests:');

                Map<String,map<String, Object>> ptoMap  = new Map<String,map<String, Object>>();
                set<string> employeeIdSet = new set<string>();

                for (Object vacationRequestWrapper : vacationRequests) {
                    Map<String, Object> vacationRequest = (Map<String, Object>) vacationRequestWrapper;
                    if (vacationRequest.get('status').equals('approved')) {
                        system.debug('vacationRequests ' + vacationRequest);
                        Map<String, Object> wrapper3 = (Map<String, Object>) vacationRequest.get('creator');

                        Map<String,Object> empValues = new Map<String,Object>(); 

                        string ptoUrl = (String) wrapper3.get('url');
                        string ptoId = (string)vacationRequest.get('id');
                        string employeeId = ptoUrl.substring(ptoUrl.length() - 7, ptoUrl.length() - 0);
                        string hours = (String)vacationRequest.get('hours');
                        decimal hoursDec = decimal.valueOf(hours);
                        string status = (String)vacationRequest.get('status');
                        system.debug('status ' + status);

                        empValues.put('startDate',vacationRequest.get('start_date'));
                        empValues.put('endDate',vacationRequest.get('end_date'));
                        empValues.put('ptoId',vacationRequest.get('id'));
                        empValues.put('hours', hoursDec);
                        system.debug('HOURS' + hoursDec);


                        empValues.put('empId', employeeId);
                        ptoMap.put(ptoId, empvalues);
                        employeeIdSet.add(employeeId);
                        system.debug('ptoMap ' + ptoMap);
                    }
                } 
                Map<String, Object> tempEmpValues = new Map<String, Object>();
                Map<String,Object> contactVal = new Map<String,Object>();
                map<String,Id> conZenIdMap = new map<String,Id>();

                List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Zenefits_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_ID__c IN : employeeIdSet];
                for (Contact con : contactList) {
                    System.debug('contactList ' + contactList);

                    conZenIdMap.put(con.Zenefits_ID__c,con.Id);
                }

                List <Time_Off_Request__c> torList = [SELECT ID, Zenefits_ID__c FROM Time_Off_Request__c WHERE Zenefits_ID__c IN : ptoMap.keySet()];
                system.debug('torlist ' + torList);
                for(Time_Off_Request__c tor1 : torList) 
                {
                    ptoMap.remove(tor1.Zenefits_ID__c); //remove existing Time Off Requests
                }

                for(String zId: ptoMap.keyset()) 
                {
                    map<String,Object> currMap = ptoMap.get(zId);
                    system.debug('Curr Map Hours ' + currMap.get('hours'));
                    map<String, Integer> hours = new Map<String, Integer>();


                    Time_Off_Request__c tor = new Time_Off_Request__c();
                    if(conZenIdMap.get((string)currMap.get('empId')) != null)
                    {
                        tor.Employee__c =conZenIdMap.get((string)currMap.get('empId')); 
                        tor.Project__c = (string)ProjectList.get('pto');
                        tor.First_Day_Off__c = date.valueof((string)currMap.get('startDate'));
                        system.debug('FirstDay ' + tor.First_Day_Off__c);
                        tor.Last_Day_Off__c = date.valueof((string)currMap.get('endDate'));
                        tor.Status__c = 'Saved';
                        tor.Zenefits_ID__c = zId;
                        tor.hours_off__c = (Decimal)currMap.get('hours');
                        system.debug('hours ' + tor.hours_off__c);

                        torToUpdate.add(TOR);
                        system.debug('torToUpdate' + torToUpdate);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
 return nextUrl;
}
```

}

I am receiving the error on this section of the code...

```
  List <Time_Off_Request__c> torList = [SELECT ID, Zenefits_ID__c FROM Time_Off_Request__c WHERE Zenefits_ID__c IN : ptoMap.keySet()];
                system.debug('torlist ' + torList);
                for(Time_Off_Request__c tor1 : torList) 
                {
                    ptoMap.remove(tor1.Zenefits_ID__c); //remove existing Time Off Requests
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop:

```
while (url != null) { 
  url = makeHttpCall(url, torToUpdate); 
}
```

And that loop performs queries...

This is why you're having problems.

What you should do is gather all the response values from the url calls, and then, only after you're done, do you query all of the contacts you're looking for.

I would say you need a static variable to store the responses, then do your post-processing once you get the null url response in this loop.

Also, you don't handle the case where a non-200 response is received... Set the default nextUrl to null to break if there's an error.

```
String nextUrl; // default null in case of error
```

---

Edit:

Here's what I would envision the code mostly looks like:

```
public class Zenefits_Time_Off implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        makeCallout();
    }
    @future(callout = true)
    public static void makeCallout() {
        string url;
        do {
            url = makeHttpCall(url);
        } while(url != null);
        processData();
    }

    static map<String,Id> ProjectList = new Map<string,Id>();
    static List<Object> vacationRequests = new List<Object>();
    static {
        for (pse__Proj__c proj : [SELECT Id, Name FROM pse__Proj__c WHERE Name Like 'PTO%'LIMIT 1]) {
            ProjectList.put('pto',proj.Id);
        }
    }

    public static String makeHttpCall(String url, List<Time_Off_Request__c> torToUpdate) {
        string nextUrl;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader();
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) { 
            // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of posts.
            Map<String, Object> wrapper = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            if(wrapper != null) {
                Map<String, Object> wrapper2 = (Map<String, Object>) wrapper.get('data');
                if (wrapper2 != null) {
                    nextUrl = (String) wrapper2.get('next_url');
                    vacationRequests.addAll((List<Object>)wrapper2.get('data'));
                }
            }
        }
        return nextUrl;
    }

    public static void processData() {
        List<Time_Off_Request__c> torToUpdate = new List<Time_Off_Request__c> ();
        Map<String,map<String, Object>> ptoMap = new Map<String,map<String, Object>>();
        set<string> employeeIdSet = new set<string>();

        for (Object vacationRequestWrapper : vacationRequests) {
            Map<String, Object> vacationRequest = (Map<String, Object>) vacationRequestWrapper;
            if (vacationRequest.get('status') == 'approved') {
                Map<String, Object> wrapper3 = (Map<String, Object>) vacationRequest.get('creator');
                Map<String,Object> empValues = new Map<String,Object>(); 
                string ptoUrl = (String) wrapper3.get('url');
                string ptoId = (string)vacationRequest.get('id');
                string employeeId = ptoUrl.substring(ptoUrl.length() - 7, ptoUrl.length() - 0);
                string hours = (String)vacationRequest.get('hours');
                decimal hoursDec = decimal.valueOf(hours);
                string status = (String)vacationRequest.get('status');
                empValues.put('startDate',vacationRequest.get('start_date'));
                empValues.put('endDate',vacationRequest.get('end_date'));
                empValues.put('ptoId',vacationRequest.get('id'));
                empValues.put('hours', hoursDec);
                empValues.put('empId', employeeId);
                ptoMap.put(ptoId, empvalues);
                employeeIdSet.add(employeeId);
            }
        } 
        Map<String, Object> tempEmpValues = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String,Object> contactVal = new Map<String,Object>();
        map<String,Id> conZenIdMap = new map<String,Id>();

        for (Contact con : [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Zenefits_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_ID__c IN : employeeIdSet]) {
            conZenIdMap.put(con.Zenefits_ID__c,con.Id);
        }
        for(Time_Off_Request__c tor1 : [SELECT ID, Zenefits_ID__c FROM Time_Off_Request__c WHERE Zenefits_ID__c IN : ptoMap.keySet()]) {
            ptoMap.remove(tor1.Zenefits_ID__c); //remove existing Time Off Requests
        }
        for(String zId: ptoMap.keyset()) {
            map<String,Object> currMap = ptoMap.get(zId);
            map<String, Integer> hours = new Map<String, Integer>();
            Time_Off_Request__c tor = new Time_Off_Request__c();
            if(conZenIdMap.get((string)currMap.get('empId')) != null) {
                tor.Employee__c =conZenIdMap.get((string)currMap.get('empId')); 
                tor.Project__c = (string)ProjectList.get('pto');
                tor.First_Day_Off__c = date.valueof((string)currMap.get('startDate'));
                tor.Last_Day_Off__c = date.valueof((string)currMap.get('endDate'));
                tor.Status__c = 'Saved';
                tor.Zenefits_ID__c = zId;
                tor.hours_off__c = (Decimal)currMap.get('hours');
                torToUpdate.add(TOR);
            }   
        }
        insert torToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Here, we make all the callouts, and gather the data together, then do the post-processing. Some edits may be required.

Comment: UGH @sfdcfox I am struggling to come up with a way to do what you are describing... Could you show me how I would go about doing that ?

Comment: @KrisWebster I've rearranged the code in a way that should probably work.

Comment: Damn @sfdcfox thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You loop infinitely.

```
while (url != null) {
    url = makeHttpCall(url, torToUpdate);
    system.debug('after while');
}
```

Your `makehttpCall` always returns a non-null value. Change your initialization within that method from:

```
string nextUrl = '';
```

to:

```
string nextUrl;
```

Default initialization value is `null`, so if you never hit an assignment block, you will exit  from your `while` loop.

Alternatively, you could use `do`/`while` with a check to `String.isNotBlank`.

```
do
{
    url = makeHttpCall(...);
}
while (String.isNotBlank(url))
```

Not really sure why you initialize the url to an empty string before your while loop, something seems to be missing here.

Comment: next_url will eventually return null, thus breaking the loop. I do agree that do-while makes more sense, though.

Comment: @adrian sorry I removed the URL for security purposes, and the URL does return null when the last set of records are reached... But I do see what sfdcfox means by hitting a query every time we hit the next URL... Okay back to the drawling board. Thanks for the help guys !